# How do i give a created user, administrator but still keep the PasswordNeverExpires option?

Tags: c#

So i want to create a new user and give it admin rights but i also need it to change the PasswordNeverExpires option to true.

```
class Program
{
    public static string Name;
    public static string Pass;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Name = "Test1";
        Pass = "Test2";
        createUser(Name, Pass);
    }

    public static void createUser(string Name, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
            {
                
                // create new newUser
                UserPrincipal newUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);


                // set some properties
                newUser.SamAccountName = Name;
                newUser.SetPassword(Password);

                // define new newUser to be enabled and password never expires
                newUser.Enabled = true;
                newUser.PasswordNeverExpires = true;


                // save new newUser
                newUser.Save();
                
            Console.WriteLine("User has been created");
        }
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I use UserPrinicipal here because when i use DirectoryEntry i can give the created user Admin rights but i havent found a way to set the PasswordNeverExpires option to true. With UserPrinicipal i can set the PasswordNeverExpires option to true, but i havent found a way to give it Admin rights.

If anyone knows how this is done, or know a way to do this better i would love to know how.

Comment: What type of machine (Mac, Xamarin)?  See the different version (upper left of page) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.passwordneverexpires?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-directoryservices-accountmanagement-authenticableprincipal-passwordneverexpires

Comment: I think you mean what kind of device i use. Its just a normal Windows pc

Comment: No.  I mean the machine.  See the pulldown on my link for the version.

Comment: .NET Platform Extensions 6

Comment: I think you need a Group.  PrincipalContext is not an account only a filter that is used on a server and doesn't have ADMIN property.  Do a search for "msdn PrincipalContext Group".  I think you need to add ADMIN to a group and then filter the group.